# не срабатывает localStorage(sesstionStorage)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу найти ошибку. Почему LocalStorage не работает? Буду признателен за помощь.

Анимация должна сработать раз, при переходе на другие странице она выключена. Но когда мы заново открываем браузер - анимация снова появляется;
У меня мультиязычнный сайт. При открытии загружается русская версия, и, естественно, это сразу записывается в sessionStorage. Когда я выбираю английский язык - анимации нет, так как она уже была.

Как можно сделать что при нажатии на `$(".lang li a")` sessionStorage очистилась и появилась анимация?

```
$(function() {
  var animation = !!parseInt(localStorage.getItem('animation'));
  if (animation) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#hand").addClass("active");
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#hand").removeClass("active");
    }, 11000);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('animation', 0);

  function changeImg() {
    var imgSrc = $("#hand img");
    var path = window.location.href;
    if (path.indexOf("http://agscoutingagency.com/") != -1) {
      imgSrc.attr("src", "http://agscoutingagency.com/wp-content/themes/agmodels/img/hand-ru-min.png");
    }
    if (path.indexOf("http://agscoutingagency.com/en") != -1) {
      imgSrc.attr("src", "http://agscoutingagency.com/wp-content/themes/agmodels/img/hand-eng-min.png");
    }
  }
  changeImg();
  $(".lang li a").click(function() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('animation');
    sessionStorage.clear()
  });
});
```

Comment: А это что за переменная "if(animation)" ?

Comment: Скорее всего переменную `isShow ` нужно переименовать в `animation`
Или `if(animation)` заменить на `if(isShow )`

Comment: при получении из localStorage значение приводится к boolean, при этом кладется в localStorage только 0, а 0 соответствует false

Answer (score -1):

```
var animation = sessionStorage.getItem('animation');
    if(animation === "false" || !sessionStorage.getItem('animation')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#hand").addClass("active");
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#hand").removeClass("active");
        }, 11000);
        sessionStorage.setItem('animation', "true");
    } 

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('animation', "true");
    }
```

Comment: как данный ответ связан с вопросом? Почему ты думаешь, что этот код  решает проблему в вопросе? В чем была проблема в вопросе?

Comment: вот решение которое работает, когда человек первый раз заходит на сайт срабатывает анимация, но когда мы смотрим другие страницы анимации нет, когда мы закроем Браузер а затем снова откроем анимация снова сработает

Comment: @Grundy ты этот текст копируешь откуда то что ли? :D

Comment: @teran, скорее часто пишу одно и то же :-)

Comment: так как он работает :) там только одна проблема осталась, у меня мультиязычный сайт когда мы заходим на него, всегда вкл русская версия, а если человек сразу переключает на анг то анимации там не будет - там анимация приветствия на анг, как можно при нажатии на ссылку агл очистить sessionStorage?

Comment: @DimaVleskov, добавь пояснения в сам ответ

Comment: проблема была что в sessionStorage(localStorage) ничего не сохранялась

Comment: @DimaVleskov, скорее ты просто не то сохранял :-)